# How to do otp verification using 2 factor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have taken free trail from 2 factor for sending sms as otp and needs to be verified again, I am able to send the sms and also console.log the status on node side, but the issue is I am not able to send the response to client weather otp is sent or not and how could I verify it

**What I have done till now**

```
let otp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000) // geterating otp

const no = req.body.cPhoneNo //phone no from UI

console.log(no)

var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "2factor.in",
    "port": null,
    "path": "/API/V1/{{api_key}}/ADDON_SERVICES/SEND/TSMS",
    "headers": {}
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    var chunks = [];
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on("end", function() {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);

        let sendData = body.toString()
        console.log(body.toString())
        res.json({status:body.toString}) //here I am getting error as type error json is not a function

    });
});
req.write(JSON.stringify({
    From: 'something',
    To: no,
    TemplateName: 'some Name',
    VAR1: 'var 1',
    VAR2: otp
        //  SendAt: '{OptionScheduleTime}' 

}));

req.end();
```

I have mentioned with comment Where I am trying to send status back to client if it is send or not, but it is not taking `json`  as throwing error `.json`  throws type error

**One more thing I found from there website is **

I have found two url end points one to send sms with some session Id and other to get otp entered from user and verify that These are two urls

To send Otp `https://2factor.in/API/V1/{api_key}/SMS/{phone_number}/AUTOGEN`

To receive Otp `https://2factor.in/API/V1/{api_key}/SMS/VERIFY/{session_id}/{otp_input}`

api_key= The key I have got from `2factor`
phone_number = receivers no

My issue is How I can use this endpoints to send the sms and to do verification, from client end I am on button click I am sending req to server via `axios` but in backend I have been suffering to send the msg and verify the otp

You can check out [this link](https://2fa.api-docs.io/v1/getting-started-with-2factor-api/steps-for-implementing-phone-verification-in-india)

Anyone out here please guide me

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `res.json` method in node's `HTTP` module. Express has `res.json` method. Instead you should use `JSON.parse`. Have a look at [this](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) example from documentation.

Comment: I have used `JSON.parse(sendData)` but still nothing is at client side

Comment: `JSON.prase` will not send it to client. It'll just parse it as JSON. To send it back to client you need to send this back via something like express. So far you're only making the call on the server side. There is no involvement of client in the code above.

Comment: look i am making post request from client via axios so `no` I am getting from client so axios is promise type so in then or catch I want to response  data or error respectively my issue is now sms is send but I am not able to send that responce on client the `then` block is not executing on client neither `catch`

Comment: What are you calling from client side? Are you invoking the above mentioned code from? If so, then just return the response that you get back.